# How does server return JWT token to the client?

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, http-headers, jwt

This is my first encounter with a JWT token and I'd like to know how is this token returned to the client after it's first created.

Should it come in the `Authorization : Bearer header` ?

Usually, it's the client that passes the token in `Authorization : Bearer header` on each request.
I'd like to know how does the server pass this token to the client after user has authenticated and the token gets created.  Also in the same header?  In a different header?

In my situation, the server will be generating the token not as a response but as part of the request.

For example:-

A user will login to a portal, then click on a link to an authorized application.  The JWT containing user claims will be passed to the authorized application as part of the request.
What is the best approach here? GET or POST? Header (which)? Query string? POST body?
Thank you!

Answer (score 28):

there is no standard for how to return JWT token to the client, however, check this URL, it answers your question

https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2/issues/82#issuecomment-129873082

> putting the JWT token in the Authorization header gives us flexibility to send an actual response in a web application. For a REST-only App/API you are free to send the JWT as the response body or a cookie. What matters is how the client stores the JWT and sends it back to the Server, which is done in the Authorization header (or Cookie or URL Token if you prefer)
>
> As for this existing in the "wild", I have not seen an example of the server sending an Authorisation header to the client, but there is nothing in the spec to suggest this is an anti-pattern.
>   see: http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html
>
> If you want to stick to the guidelines you would do follow this example: http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html#ExAccTokResp

Answer (score 9):

One may be interested to know that the [OAuth 2.0 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1) specifies the response body for that purpose:

> 5.1.  Successful Response
>
> The authorization server issues an access token and optional refresh
> token, and constructs the response by adding the following parameters
> to the entity-body of the HTTP response with a 200 (OK) status code:
>
> `access_token`
> REQUIRED.  The access token issued by the authorization server.
> [...]

Comment: Worth noting that `token_type` is also a required attribute. This could be for example `Bearer`